Convert File Share URL to File Full Path
I want a flow that will convert any type of link of a file to its full path.
To have better understanding of the requirements below is the detailed explanation with sample case -
Let, the file name is SampleFile.docx now the File Path I want is https://SiteUrl.com/Shared%20Documents/SampleFile.docx from the file links as below where all of the links are referring to the same file.

https://SiteUrl.com/ETqedFnA8jhBqPtXEjO78hMBsW7a6fSKiNuCKiqVEmd5og
https://SiteUrl.com/:p:/r/teams/SiteName/Shared%20Documents/SampleFile?d=w1e79c3943c01408283331df19ab9a45b&csf=1&web=1&e=kng6Gl


You can't get the file path by the sharelink. When you are invited, you only ha ve the permission to the file. So you don't have permission to get the path of folder or library.It's an expected behavior
